# Javascript external file doesnt work

Tags: javascript

anotherI have a html page where I include file with javascript functions. `<script src="script.js"></script>`
The javascript file:

```
function err(errRep) {
    alert(errRep);                  
}

function next(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('another').style.backgroundColor=#8CDD81;                  
}
```

If there is only one function everything works fine but when I add next function any of my functions doesn't work. What is problem?

Comment: Does your browser's development console show an error that you can attach to the question?

Comment: Your javascript is not valid that is why. It breaks the rest of the file. You should have quotes around your color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, you have to iterate or index it. You also have a syntax error: `#8CDD81` is not valid JS syntax, you need quotes around the string.

```
function next(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('another')[0].style.backgroundColor='#8CDD81';                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely that is syntax issue. You need wrap your `backgroundColor` value into `''`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('another').style.backgroundColor='#8CDD81';
```

Comment: Still wrong) something like `backgroundColor of undefined` will thrown